# how to keep log file foreever in laravel application?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, nginx

I found that log file is deleted BY end of the day from my laravel log directory. Please suggest what setting should apply to keep my log file forever.

Comment: which laravel version are you using ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the following file:

**vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Log/Writer.php**

and find the following function:

```
public function useDailyFiles($path, $days = 0, $level = 'debug')
    {
        $this->monolog->pushHandler(
            $handler = new RotatingFileHandler($path, $days, $this->parseLevel($level))
        );

        $handler->setFormatter($this->getDefaultFormatter());
    }
```

You can set parameter for `$days` variable. e.g. `$days = 365`

Comment: Thank Ali, I tried this on my local and it is working. I will deploy on live. Thanks again.